# Implicit conversion of optionals

Tags: scala

I want to make expressions like these:

```
val input: Option[String] = Option("123")
val longOption1: Option[Long] = input
println(longOption1)
// Some(123)

val longOption2: Option[Long] = Option("abc")
println(longOption2)
// None
```

I had this attempt:

```
object OptionalConverter {
  implicit val string2Long = (s: String) => s.toLong
  implicit val string2Int = (s: String) => s.toInt

  implicit def convert[A, B](input: Option[A])(implicit mapper: A => B): Option[B] = input.flatMap(i => Try(mapper(i)).toOption)
}
```

However it doesn't work and I'm a bit stuck..

I'm not sure if my usage is even possible or if I have to make it to be at least something along the lines of `val result = convert[Option[Long]](Option("123"))` in order for it to compile.

Any hints appreciated!

Comment: It is possible but you don't want to use it. Implicit conversions cause all kind of debugging issues and unforeseeable consequences. You may want to be able to write something like `val longOption1 = input.convert[Option[Long]]` or `val longOption1 Option[Long] = input.convert` since it will convert only these parts of code that you want to and make it easy to review where conversion happens.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok I am curious if you have any idea why it is not working though? 
I mean `Option("abc")` I get - there is no mapper. But even removing that, it's weird. Scala 3 accepts `val x: Option[Long] = input`, but _not_ `val x: Option[Long] = Option("123")`, and scala 2 is _the other way around_ (and additionally complains about `.toLong` and `.toInt` not being valid) 
https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Urxloda5QQGNnwYhyfBm2Q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it won't works is that you have conflicting implicits. Since there is more than one way of convert `Option[String]` to `Option[Int]` compiler cannot know which should be used and doesn't use any of them.

You can see it when you use `-Yno-predef` compiler option:

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions
import scala.util.Try

object OptionalConverter {
  import scala.Predef.augmentString
  implicit val string2Long: String => Long = java.lang.Long.parseLong(_)
  //implicit val string2Int: String => Int = java.lang.Integer.parseInt(_)

  implicit def convert[A, B](input: Option[A])(implicit
      mapper: A => B
  ): Option[B] = input.flatMap(i => Try(mapper(i)).toOption)
}

import OptionalConverter._



val input: Option[String] = Option("123")
val longOpt: Option[Long] = input
scala.Predef.println(longOpt)


//val intOpt: Option[Int] = Option("123")
//scala.Predef.println(intOpt)
```

(see: [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/MateuszKubuszok/Zuh0YI9bR9O85NRqWNCR6g/19)).

This code compiles and prints what you expect. However,

- it stops working if you uncomment `implicit val string2Int: String => Int` - perhaps, since you can convert `Long` to `Int` (and vice versa) this native `implicit A => B` becomes ambiguous
- if you leave `string2Int` commented out but remove `-Yno-predef` then implicit conversions from `scala.Predef` would clash with `string2Long` and also make it ambiguous
- at the same time you cannot just enable `Predef` and comment out `string2int` and `string2Long`, it doesn't work as well

This highlight how many traps are there with implicit conversions and how easily it is for them to clash in unpredictable way (which is not as bad as them resulting in a compiling code that shouldn't compile because their mix results in unwanted behavior).

For that reasons using of some extension method with a type class is preferred as it constrains implicit-based behavior to a single use-case which helps debugging things and taming the behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Using very general implicit is almost always a bad idea as it can lead to very unpredictable result.

Instead of using bare `A => B` as implicit converters you should instead encapsulate this conversion behaviour in it's own construct. This will prevent the unpredictability and bugs introduced by un-intended converter candidates.

So, you can define something like a `OptionConverter` trait and then use it `implicitly` in your code.

```scala
  trait OptionConverter[A, B] {
    def convert(o: Option[A]): Option[B]
  }

  object OptionConverter {

    implicit val intToString: OptionConverter[Int, String] = new OptionConverter[Int, String] {
      override def convert(o: Option[Int]): Option[String] = o.map(_.toString())
    }

    implicit val stringToString: OptionConverter[String, Int] = new OptionConverter[String, Int] {
      override def convert(o: Option[String]): Option[Int] = o.map(s => Integer.parseInt(s))
    }
    
  }

  implicit class OptionConverterOps[A](o: Option[A]) {
    def convert[B](implicit oc: OptionConverter[A, B]): Option[B] = oc.convert(o)
  }

  val intOption = Option("10").convert[Int]

  val stringOption = Option(10).convert[String]
```